# NAS Device not picking up after IP reset

Tags: nas

I have this 3.5" Gigabit Lan Disk enclosure. I had to reset the IP address to its factory settings by depressing a button behind it for 15-20 seconds. Reason for the resetting was that the company lost the password for this NAS device. After I reset it to its factory settings, its IP address is suppose to be 169.254.0.1, so I also changed my laptop's IP address to its range to be able to access it. No luck. Then I changed my IP address to dynamic(DHCP).. I saw a change in my IP... Something that is not in range with the NAS device's IP. It assigned me an IP of 169.254.104.161... Isn't that a bit strange?? why is it giving me an IP with 104 except 0?

Comment: What do you know about the DHCP server?

Comment: The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved 169.254.0.0-169.254.255.255 for Automatic Private IP Addressing.

Comment: 169.254.104.161 is a APIA or link local address.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address not assigned by your DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Because the NAS is a static IP and yours is Dynamic.

Comment: i need to know why is it giving me an ip out of its own range

Comment: Can anyone tell me HOW EXACTLY you need to reset the 3.5" Gigabit Lan Disk Enclosure? It seems that I didn't reset it completely that is why I am getting this weird IP ranges from it..